# If let statement error

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement, swift3, let

Im trying to build a todo list with coreData, my goal is to have an error pop-up notification if a user tries to just click the "add" button without entering any text in the text-field.
I currently have the pop-up notification working but once i dismiss the notification and then add text into the text-field and click the "add" button the application crashes.

```
@IBAction func addBtnTaskPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    let task = Task(context: context)

    //have to add an if let here.
    if let text = textField.text, !text.isEmpty{
        task.name = textField.text
        //save data to coredata
        (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()
    } else {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error:", message: "Cannot Add Empty Task", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Continue", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Where is it crashing? What line? What is the error message?

Comment: fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")  takes me to that  line of code in the AppDelegate.swift

Comment: there is something wrong when you try to saveContext() re you trying to save `textField.text` in your entity `Task`? What type is `task.name`?

Comment: @mat seems like thats the issue but if i enter "test" or any text in the textField and click the button it saves it fine, the crash occurs when i click the button with the textField empty my alter pops up i dismiss it and then try to add a task and then the app crashes

Comment: task.name is a String type

Comment: how do you know the text  is being saved in coreData ? Are you able to retrieve it when you launch the app again ?

Comment: Try moving creation of the `Task` to the `if let`.

Comment: @mat text is being saved in coreData. If i type in lets say "test" and then click  the add button it saves it and takes me back to the list which is what i want it to do. My main goal is if the user tries to add a empty task pop up a error message when they dismiss the pop up message and then add a task

Comment: Try moving the first two lines inside the if statement: `let context = ...`, `let task = ...`. Task object may be causing an error when de-initializing with empty Task. Hard to tell without seeing the Task class.

Comment: It's pretty silly to optional bind `textField.text` to `text` but then use the unwrapped optional. Don't you get a warning about the unused variable?

Comment: @user7417272 "fatalError("Unresolved error (nserror), (nserror.userInfo)") takes me to that line of code in the AppDelegate.swift " to which line?

Comment: @shallowThought it's on line 87 in AppDelegate.swift

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not saving coreData properly. Try this (I haven't tested it though)

```
@IBAction func addBtnTaskPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
    let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Task", in: context)
    let task = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context) as! Task


    //have to add an if let here.
    if let text = textField.text, !text.isEmpty{
    task.name = textField.text
    //save data to coredata
       do {
           try context.save()
           print("saved!")
       } catch let error as NSError  {
        print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
       }        
    } else {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error:", message: "Cannot Add Empty     Task", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Continue", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but this solution didn't work, the problem is not saving it to core data because if i type something into the text field it saves it into coreData, but if i purposely add a task without any text and pop up the "alert", dismiss the "alert" and then try to add text into the textField and then add the task to coreData it crashes the app.